# Stacked Group Bar from Chart.js : Can I give each stack group a unique color?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, chart.js

For regular bar charts you can pass an array of colors, for stacked group bar charts I simply cannot find a way out the box to feed it an array and give it a color PER group. Each day would have 2 bars and that duo of bars should have an individual color per day, fed by an array I retrieve.

Is there a way to tweak this for this to work? Feels like it's more complicated than it really should be.

E.G Day 1 group would be green, Day 2 group red, Day 3 blue. Etc Color coded according to what each day has registered for it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFysC.jpg

In this photo example i'd have 4 different colors

```
    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart2').getContext('2d');
        var myChart2 = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: [";
    echo $dateLabelArray;
    echo "],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'AM',             backgroundColor:
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.7)'
                ,
                borderColor:
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
                ,
                borderWidth: 1.5,
                    stack: 'Stack 0',
                    data: [";
    echo $amArray;
    echo "]
                }, {
                    label: 'PM', backgroundColor:
                    'rgba(28, 159, 246, 0.7)'
                ,
                borderColor:
                    'rgba(28, 159, 246, 1)'
                ,
                borderWidth: 1.5,
                    stack: 'Stack 1',
                    data: [";
    echo $pmArray;
    echo "]
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [
                        {
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                callback: function (label, index, labels) {
                                    switch (label) {
                                        case 0:
                                            return 'Challenged';
                                        case 1:
                                            return 'Positive';
                                        case 2:
                                            return 'Neutral';

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by using the same colour array for each dataset, e.g.:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart2').getContext('2d'),
  dateLabelArray = ['2019-06-10', '2019-06-09', '2019-06-08', '2019-06-07'],
  amArray = [2, 1, 2, 1],
  pmArray = [2, 1, 2, 1],
  colours = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow'],
  myChart2 = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: dateLabelArray,
      datasets: [{
          label: 'AM',
          backgroundColor: colours,
          borderColor: colours,
          borderWidth: 1.5,
          stack: 'Stack 0',
          data: amArray
        },
        {
          label: 'PM',
          backgroundColor: colours,
          borderColor: colours,
          borderWidth: 1.5,
          stack: 'Stack 1',
          data: pmArray
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          stacked: true
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          stacked: true,
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            callback: function(label, index, labels) {
              switch (label) {
                case 0:
                  return 'Challenged';
                case 1:
                  return 'Positive';
                case 2:
                  return 'Neutral';
              }
            }
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
```